# Flamingo (Anthurium) getting translucent heart shaped patches at the tip

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis

I'm new to keeping plants. My 3 month old flamingo plant keeps getting these transparent spots right at the tip that slowly spreads and then become brown. Some time later the older leaves and all flowers turned brown and fell off, with stem going very yellow. I've trimmed those away. And while new leaves that have since sprouted and looked healthy... the tell take transparent spots are reappearing. See below:

[image]

How I've been watering/feeding: I have a layer of pebbles underneath the inner pot. And keep the pebbles moist most of the week without letting the plant pot touch the water. I also mist the leaves every now and then. And Dunk the plant in quarter strength house plant fertiliser every month for 5 mins or so. It sits in a well lit room with a patio door. But the plant is far enough away that it doesn't get direct sunlight.

I tried diagnosing the issue by reading around. But everything under the sun seems to cause leaf browning. Please help.

note: one thing that may or may not be related is that there are these very tiny white insect that I find floating about in the water and in the soil. They don't seem to be on or under the leaves.